# how to deploy in different environment (dev, uat ,prod) using cdk pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, environment, aws-cdk

When I commit to develop branch it must deploy code to specific environment (dev). Similarly when i deploy to uat branch it must deploy to uat environment. How do i achieve this functionality in aws cdk pipeline ?
There is stage and be deployed to multiple region but need to define if pushed to this branch then deploy to this environment likewise.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach depends on a few factors including whether your stack is environment agnostic or not (i.e. whether it needs to look up resources from within a given account.)

For simply switching between different accounts and regions, the CDK team has a decent writeup [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html) which recommends a small wrapper script for each environment that injects the configuration by way of `CDK_DEPLOY_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEPLOY_REGION` environment variables.

If you want to provide other synth time context then you can do so via the [context API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html), which allows you to provide configuration 'in six different ways':

> Automatically from the current AWS account.
>
> Through the --context option to the cdk command.
>
> In the project's cdk.context.json file.
>
> In the project's cdk.json file.
>
> In the context key of your ~/.cdk.json file.
>
> In your AWS CDK app using the construct.node.setContext method.

Comment: To clarify, 'you' should not provide configuration using 'cdk.context.json', this file should only be modified by the cdk npm module. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html

Answer (score 2):

My team uses the inline context args to define an environment name, and from the environment name, it reads a json config file that defines many environment-dependent parameters.

```
cdk deploy --context env=Dev
```

We let the environment name determine the branch name and set it accordingly on the 'Branch' property of the 'GitHubSourceAction'. (C# code)

```
string env = (string)this.Node.TryGetContext("env");

var pipeline = new CdkPipeline(this, "My-Pipeline", new CdkPipelineProps()
{
    SourceAction = new GitHubSourceAction(new GitHubSourceActionProps()
    {
        Branch = env
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @nsquires. This has helped me.